How to Link Existing Keycloak Users with an Alternative Identity Provider?
I am using Keycloak as an identity provider to provide SSO for a series of applications using OpenID. Until now, only username and password login was allowed. I have added an alternative identity provider that allows authentication with a unique ID. The problem I have is that I don't know how to link a login with the alternative identity provider to an existing user in Keycloak.
Is there a way to redirect a user who has logged in with a username and password to the login with the alternative identity provider for this association?
Is there a way to redirect to the username and password login after authentication with the alternative IDP?
Thank you in advance for your help!
I am not sure how to proceed with this.

Just as a pointer for people that arrives here: you can configure in the authentication tab, a flow that redirects to the IDP and then set that flow
